Proof-of-Work Challenge with a Built-In Advantage
I come here feeling like Don Quixote chasing windmills. I'm a complete newbie in cryptography, but I find myself trying to solve a problem without even knowing if it's solvable.
I want to design a proof-of-work (PoW) system for a competitive game with the following properties:

Random Challenge: A random string is presented to all players at the beginning. This works like a common input for everyone. The second input, which is available to everyone, is Neo's public key (we'll discuss this in the next section).

Goal: The challenge resembles the one in Bitcoin PoW. The winner is the one who computes a sort of "longest string possible." Which string should be calculated? Something that can be derived from the inputs (the initial random string and Neo's public key). This should be modeled in a way that makes it easy to see who did the most amount of work.

PK/SK: All participants have secp256k1 key pairs (public and private keys).


Neo's Advantage

Neo's Role: Neo's public key is used to set up the game, but he doesn't compete himself. His keys are part of the input given to all competitors.
His Powers:

He can solve any challenge instantly, if needed (using his private keys).
The challenge can be generated using only his public key (and the random string that is common knowledge).
Everyone can verify, based on Neo’s public key alone, that he possesses this advantage.



Since the challenge is crafted exclusively using Neo's public key and a random string, Neo himself doesn't even know the existence of the challenge beforehand — but he can always win if he decides to participate.

Is it possible to build something like this using the basic building blocks of cryptography?

I think more details would help answer your question. My first idea is using a PoW similar to Bitcoin, where you give the players a random string and they have to create an additional random string to compute hashes with certain properties (e.g. n zeros at the beginning). Then you can make the players create multiple hash values and for each additional hash, the hardness of the PoW increases (e.g. n=i for the i-th hash).

What details can help? The idea is to calculate the number of characters in something. A random string, S, is publicly available for everyone to use. It's like a public knowledge that will be presented in be beginning of the game. The game is constructed using this string S and Neo’s public key. Neo can solve the problem quickly (using his private keys), but other participants can only brute force it (similar to mining for a solution). Whoever calculates the most characters for this challenge (whether it’s from the original string S or something derived from it) wins.
